# save dropdown value in viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net

i create custom page that shows articles,I added dropdown where i can select the sort order,and also I realized custom paging.
here is the code

```
var sortOrder = new List<string> {"Title", "Date", "Author"};

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    sortOrderDropDownList.DataSource = sortOrder;
    sortOrderDropDownList.DataBind();
}

articles = articles.OrderBy(a => a.Heading).ToList();

if (IsPostBack)
{
    switch (sortOrderDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value)
    {
       case "Date":
           articles = articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.StartDate).ToList();
           break;
       case "Author":
           articles = articles.OrderBy(a => a.AuthorComment).ToList();
           break;
       default:
          articles = articles.OrderBy(a => a.Heading).ToList();
          break;
     }
}

this.ArticleRepeater.DataSource = articles;

if (articles.Count > 10)
{
     int count = articles.Count - (number - 1) * 10 >= 10 ? 10 : articles.Count - (number - 1) * 10 - 1;
     this.ArticleRepeater.DataSource = articles.GetRange((number - 1) * 10, count);
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     if (number > 1)
     {
        stringBuilder.AppendFormat("<a href='{0}?page={1} '>&lt; Prev</a>  |  ", Request.Url.AbsolutePath, (number - 1));
        stringBuilder.AppendFormat("<b>Page {0}</b>", number);
        if (articles.Count > number * 10)
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("  |  <a href='{0}?page={1}'>Next &gt;</a>", Request.Url.AbsolutePath, (number + 1));

        this.ArticlePaginator.Text = string.Format("<div class='ArticleListPagination'>{0}</div>", stringBuilder);
      }

      this.ArticleRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

I add `autoPostBack ='true'` to dropdown,and wneh I choose from `dropdown`, my articles are sorted, but the selected value from `dropdown` doesn't saves when I go to next page(because i create dropdown every time when page is created)
how can I save the `dropdown` value into viewstate? I also set `EnableViewState="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled"` on dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewState` is saved in page body, so when you go to different page new `ViewState` is created. To save a value between going different pages use `Session`, `Cookies` or `QueryString`.

Comment: Read some of this: [cookies way](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31914/Beginner-s-Guide-To-ASP-NET-Cookies), [session](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/)